Safely removing square recessed light with potential asbestos insulation
I am removing the ceiling of a sunroom constructed at some unknown time many decades ago. The house itself is from the 20s but the sunroom is not. I was starting the process by removing the old school square recessed lights when I saw that they contain an insulating foil that contains a white substance. I am worried its asbestos, but not sure since it seems somewhat soft, i.e. was stapled through.
Any tips for removing the lights in a way that will minimize disturbing the insulation?


tape over the insulation with packing tape, or paint over it with white glue. so long as it hangs together it's not a danger to you.

Try to remove the thing as a unit. You probably don't need to actually disassemble it. There seem to be screws on the outer flanges that would allow this.
Put on a good mask (properly) which is rated for fine dust, keep active ventilation to clear the area, and get it done. Vacuum the area when you're finished, keeping the cloud blowing outside.
Folks tend to make a much bigger deal out of this than it is. Asbestos is dangerous in a cumulative fashion over time. This little cleanup isn't that.

Asbestos only poses a potential health risk when it is fraying or crumbling, and when fibers are released in the air. Asbestos fibers that are undisturbed and kept away from the interior environment of a home or building pose little risk. For example asbestos enclosed behind walls, isolated in attics or bound tightly in an intact product.
Asbestos exposure and related diseases have been reported in asbestos workers and their families. It has also been reported in those who live near asbestos mines or processing facilities. Construction and trade workers involved in renovations and repairs to older buildings are at higher risk of asbestos exposure if safety measures are not followed.
https://www.healthlinkbc.ca/healthlinkbc-files/asbestos-when-should-i-worry


That was my thought too, though I was wondering if the inner flange opened up to where the connections are made with the junction box. After more thought I think you are right, that the connections are probably behind that larger flange. I think my plan is wear a respirator and create negative air pressure in the room with a box fan, then carefully cover the exposed edges with tape before attempting to remove the lightbulb assembly as a unit.

Right, but it's less about air pressure than air flow. You want any particles blowing out of your immediate zone.

Yes, good point. I meant use a fan to create  air flow that pulls air out of the work area and towards the outdoors.
